# Using the option --help

Tags: command-line

I've been tinkering around the terminal on ubuntu and noticed that by using

```
aspell --help
```

I got the very detailed documentation about the command aspell. Whereas when I use

```
look --help
```

All I get is

```
look: invalid option -- '-'
usage: look [-bdf] [-t char] string [file ...]
```

I wish to be able to retrieve explicit documentation about every command in order to familiarize myself with options usage and meaning. (Without having to search for it online)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What options are supported by a utility is a variable. In general, you can try the options `-h`, `--help` and the `man` and `info` commands:

```
man look
info look
```

The manpages are also available online (http://manpages.ubuntu.com), so you can look them up even if they are not installed.

In general, the best method is to look at the manpages. They are the standard source of information in Unix-like systems.

Comment: Thank you :) The man command was really what I was looking for.